# Custom window grid in 12.04

Tags: window-management

I'm using classic gnome in 12.04. Is there some way to have a custom grid for resizing windows? CompizConfig allows me to configure the "grid" feature, but it only supports resizing to half the screen. Is there some way that I can set a custom size and location for the active window using key bindings? I've tried using xdotool, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is QuickTile, which can be found here:

http://ssokolow.com/quicktile/

I never figured out how to customize it, because I changed my monitor setup to an entirely different solution, but if you come across this question and want a solution, this program should work quite well.

Comment: Customization depends on what you want to do. Either way, it's easy but, because I haven't had time to write a new config file parser, you can only edit keybindings in the config file. Adding new positions to bind has to be done by opening `quicktile.py` in your favorite text editor and adjusting the table of positions near the top of the file.